# How to send ArrayList<File> with single key in retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

there are lots of example that shows how to send multiple file but they are with different key in multi part body request but i wont to send with one single key.
how to achieve this?

Comment: They key identifiers each file so how would you identifier the different files if they all get sent under one key?

Comment: @Nkole Evans, my need is like for section1 there are 3 files and for section2 there are 2 files, thats why i dont need identifier for each file and also i want to try like i questioned